# How to move files to trash from command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

I do a lot of terminal work, and today had the experience of typing

```
rm fileInQuestion.txt
```

Before finding out that I did actually need fileInQuestion.txt. If I'd deleted in the GUI then I would have just gotten it out of the Trash. I'd like to know if it's possible to overload 'rm' in the Terminal in such a way that it sends the file/files to the Trash on the way out.

Comment: There are programs that can recover deleted files (as long as those sectors on the hard drive are not overwritten in the mean time!).  When this happens, you should use one of those...

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/q/468721/250556 for googlers looking for ubuntu/debian/linux file trashing.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

I wouldn't advise aliasing `rm` to `mv` as you might get in the habit of `rm` not permanently deleting files and then run into issues on other computers or under other user accounts when it *does* permanently delete.

I wrote a set of `bash` scripts that add more Mac OS X-like command line tools (in addition to a number of the built-in ones like `open`, `pbcopy`, `pbpaste`, etc.), most importantly `trash`. My version of `trash` will do all the correct things that aliasing `rm` won't (and hopefully nothing bad, but I've been using it on my own Macs for a few years now without any lost data), including: renaming the file like Finder does if a file with the same name already exists, putting files in the correct Trash folder on external volumes; it also has some added niceties, like: it attempts to use AppleScript when available so you get the nice trash sound and such (but doesn't require it so you can still use it via SSH when no user is logged in), it can give you Trash size across all volumes.

You can grab my [tools-osx suite from my site](https://web.archive.org/web/20180607044643/http://www.makkintosshu.com/development) or the latest and greatest version from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/morgant/tools-osx).

There's also [a `trash` command developed by Ali Rantakari](http://hasseg.org/trash/), but I haven't tested that one myself.

Comment: Excellent answer, much better than mine!

Comment: I've used `trash` by Rantakari for quite a while and can really vouch for it. It is compiled Objective-C and cleverly uses standard filesystem APIs and, should it fail (ie. user doesn't have sufficient rights), it calls Finder to trash the files (effectively prompting for authentication). You can read more info of `trash` from [hasseg.org/blog](http://hasseg.org/blog/post/406/trash-files-from-the-os-x-command-line/).

Comment: trash is also available via the brew package manager. just use: `brew install trash`.

Comment: @landon9720 Good point. And, to clarify for others, the `trash` command available through [Homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/) is Alai Rantakari's (see the [`brew` formula](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/trash.rb)).

Comment: @landon9720 love me some homebrew trash!

Comment: I just saw your git page: 336 lines of bash code to move a file to the trash? ;)

Comment: @CousinCocaine Haha, yes, it could use some consolidation after all these years. That said, it's well commented and supports a lot of functionality (trash across multiple volumes, moving to trash directly or via AppleScript, empty & secure empty, etc.), so it wouldn't be particularly short anyway. :)

Comment: @morgant, indeed. It looks clean and very complete. Nice.

Comment: I have been using Ali Rantakari's `trash` command for years, and I like it. But I upgraded to Yosemite and it stopped working. I get an error saying `-bash: /usr/bin/trash: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I was able to fix the error by running `brew remove trash` and then `brew install trash`.

Comment: are link-only answers actually acceptable here?  They aren't on stack overflow.  There's nothing here actually answering the question other than a link they may go bad at any time.

Comment: @xaxxon I appreciate your question. As the author of this answer, my original goal was to answer the question in the first paragraph (advising against aliasing `rm`), then provide alternate solutions. Others certainly seem to feel that my answer most thoroughly answered the question, but I’m happy to expand upon my first paragraph if you feel it would be helpful.

Comment: @morgant Advising against something is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: site is down. rip.

Comment: @CarterPape I know why you had to put 'rip' after 'site is down', smart choice :))

Comment: The site is back up, though most of the updates have been in the GitHub repo.

Comment: Many comments here talk about the alternative `trash` command installed by `brew install trash`. To be clear, that trash does not by default use the Finder anymore, so "Put Back" will not work unless you use a flag. Even when you do use the flag, it often errors (which is why the default was changed). 
So, morgant's script is of higher quality. It can be installed using zinit with this command `zinit wait'1' lucid light-mode as"program" pick"src/trash" for morgant/tools-osx`

Answer (score 167):

The [trash](https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash) command line tool can be installed via `brew install trash` or `port install trash`.

It allows you to restore trashed files via command line or the Finder.

Comment: What an elegant solution!

Comment: Also available in macports: `port install trash`

Comment: every time I try to `brew install trash`, I get this: http://pastebin.com/N92cM7d8

Comment: @BenC.R.Leggiero I would take that issue over to https://github.com/ali-rantakari/trash/issues. Did you `brew update` first? Works good on my end.

Comment: @PaulWenzel yes, and it seems to update just fine. I'll post an issue.

Comment: Seems like a pretty heavy solution for something we can do with a [simple Python script](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/162354/25276).

Answer (score 33):

I have an executable called `rem` somewhere in my `$PATH` with the following contents:

EDIT: code below is a [revised and improved version](https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/14fedc316441c350b382528ea64bc09c) in collaboration with [Dave Abrahams](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/25276/dave-abrahams):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    files = []
    for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
        if os.path.exists(arg):
            p = os.path.abspath(arg).replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('"', '\\"')
            files.append('the POSIX file "' + p + '"')
        else:
            sys.stderr.write(
                "%s: %s: No such file or directory\n" % (sys.argv[0], arg))
    if len(files) > 0:
        cmd = ['osascript', '-e',
               'tell app "Finder" to move {' + ', '.join(files) + '} to trash']
        r = subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
        sys.exit(r if len(files) == len(sys.argv[1:]) else 1)
else:
    sys.stderr.write(
        'usage: %s file(s)\n'
        '       move file(s) to Trash\n' % os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(64) # matches what rm does on my system
```

It behaves in exactly the same way as deleting from the Finder. (See blog post [here](http://www.anthonysmith.me.uk/2008/01/08/moving-files-to-trash-from-the-mac-command-line/).)

Comment: This should have more points IMO. Because it is AppleScript it uses the actual trash process to move the file to trash, which means it will behave exactly the same. Shame a one-liner was not provided however.

Comment: Well, someone downvoted it on Oct 31 '15 at 10:26 - at precisely the same time that someone else was posting an answer to this question!

Comment: This answer is an object lesson in how to do things right. It works with shell wildcards *and* it works through the Finder. It doesn't reinvent any wheels, and it's about as simple as can be. I put it in my `~/bin`, named it `trash`, and it worked the first time—enabling me to trash a whole lot of files way more efficiently than if I had to click on them in Finder windows. Much gratitude. I hope you'll post more answers!

Comment: Unfortunately, the script does not handle `'`characters in file names. I was trying to use it with one of those "(John Doe's conflict copy)" files that Dropbox sometimes creates, when it failed on me.

Comment: [This version](https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/14fedc316441c350b382528ea64bc09c) handles quotes. It changes error handling behavior a bit, which in the version above seems to be not-very-carefully-worked-out (errors to stdout instead of stderr, no exit code) but the error you get from `osascript` when the file doesn't exist is not beautiful so you might want to tune that part.

Comment: Nice job. [This version](https://gist.github.com/anthonyjsmith/e0d482bc3fe8ef9e0eb698757efc7624) incorporates those changes, and also (1) tries to imitate the shell command `rm` as much as possible in terms of displaying messages when files don't exist, and (2) collates everything into a single `osascript` call.

Comment: One-upping: https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/14fedc316441c350b382528ea64bc09c

Comment: @DaveAbrahams: This is clearly THE answer :)  To be "unixly correct" (UC),the script should be installed as [`/usr/local/bin`](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch04s09.html#usrlocalshare1) (or, `/usr/local/share` if you prefer). Name the file  `/usr/local/bin/trash` , and: `sudo chmod a+rx usr/local/bin/trash`.

Answer (score 21):

Use the terminal command osascript, the AppleScript interpreter.

```
osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to delete POSIX file \"${PWD}/${InputFile}\""
```

This tells AppleScript to tell Finder to send the file to trash.

PWD is needed for relative file paths, as AppleScript does not handle that well.

Comment: Simple, effective, and no need to install anything! Nice.

Answer (score 9):

a modern approach using swift

https://github.com/reklis/recycle

```
//
// main.swift
// recycle
//
// usage: recycle <files or directories to throw out>
//

import Foundation
import AppKit

var args = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().arguments
args.removeAtIndex(0) // first item in list is the program itself

var w = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace()
var fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

for arg in args {
    let path = arg.stringByStandardizingPath;
    let file = path.lastPathComponent
    let source = path.stringByDeletingLastPathComponent

    w.performFileOperation(NSWorkspaceRecycleOperation,
        source:source,
        destination: "",
        files: [file],
        tag: nil)
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @jherran thanks for the reminder, I added a code segment

Comment: This is my preferred answer because it uses the same underlying logic and APIs as the GUI.

Comment: Now if only there were a Python version that avoided the need for a 3MB binary to make one system call.

Answer (score 3):

I found a pretty nice code that can be added at the end of user's batch profile and causes `rm` to move the files to the trash each time it is run.

**nano ~/.bash_profile**

```
#... append at the end
function rm () {
  local path
  for path in "$@"; do
    # ignore any arguments
    if [[ "$path" = -* ]]; then :
    else
      # remove trailing slash
      local mindtrailingslash=${path%/}
      # remove preceding directory path
      local dst=${mindtrailingslash##*/}
      # append the time if necessary
      while [ -e ~/.Trash/"$dst" ]; do
        dst="`expr "$dst" : '\(.*\)\.[^.]*'` `date +%H-%M-%S`.`expr "$dst" : '.*\.\([^.]*\)'`"
      done
      mv "$path" ~/.Trash/"$dst"
    fi
  done
}
```

source: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20080224175659423

Comment: This is v clever but I still wouldn't recommend this.  It's clever because its in the bash profile for the user and so only the user can execute this version of the function by typing it in, scripts that rely on rm will still call the original.  But I wouldn't recommend doing this because the user will get used to rm acting in this way when it doesn't on other machines.  I'm going to use this but rename the function "trash"

Comment: I am using the same function with two changes: ① I corrected a bug in the function that causes any folder to be renamed to the timestamp, if it has been tab-completed to include a trailing slash: This requires the following changes: Replacing the line `local dst=${path##*/}` with `local dst=${mindtrailingslash##*/}` and inserting another line just before that one that says `local mindtrailingslash=${path%/}`. ② I use the name `function rr`. Like this, it does not interefere with plain `rm`, but the name is similarly short and fast to type (any other name would do).

Comment: Change the name of `rm()` to `rmt()` - This way you can still use the `rm` command when you want. I think of rmt in my head as `remove to trash` :D

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty trivial one-line solution to add to your bash profile. Note that it will overwrite something with the same name in the trash already.

```
trash() { mv -fv "$@" ~/.Trash/ ; }
```

Usage:

```
• ~/Desktop $$$ touch a b c
• ~/Desktop $$$ ls
a b c
• ~/Desktop $$$ trash a b c
a -> /Users/ryan.tuck/.Trash/a
b -> /Users/ryan.tuck/.Trash/b
c -> /Users/ryan.tuck/.Trash/c
• ~/Desktop $$$ ls
• ~/Desktop $$$
```

Comment: have edited accordingly - thank you for the input!

Answer (score 3):

This is an improvement to the answers given by [Antony Smith](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/162354) and [cde](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/310084).

The problem with embedding a filename in a string that is passed to `osascript` via `-e` is that, on modern Unix-like systems, filenames can contain quotes, to the effect that parts of the filename could be run as AppleScript.

A safer way to do this is to read the filename from an environment variable:

```sh
trash() (
    : "${1:?}"
    case $1 in
        (/*) FNAME="$1" ;;
        (*)  FNAME="$(pwd)/$1"
    esac
    export FNAME
    exec osascript <<-EOF >/dev/null
        set fName to system attribute "FNAME"
        tell application "Finder" to delete my (POSIX file fName)
    EOF
)
```

If you add this function to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`, you can call `trash` from the command line. **EDIT:** Though turning this into a function that is actually useful requires more work, of course.

Comment: Nice. I forgot that hfs + and apfs allow " and other special characters in filename. But if you use quotes in filenames, there's a 8th level of \"hell\".

Answer (score 2):

There are two utilities installable via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) that can accomplish this:

1. ## [trash](https://hasseg.org/trash/)

   This is a small command-line program for OS X that moves files or folders to the trash. The USP of this command is that enables to easily restore the files. A command to trash files/folders is no use if you can't restore files/folders after trashing them. From the command's website:

> By default, trash asks Finder to move the specified files/folders to the trash instead of calling the system API to do this because of the "put back" feature that only works when trashing files through Finder.

> -F
>
> Ask Finder to move the files to the trash, instead of using the system API. This is slower, but it utilizes Finder's UI (e.g. sounds) and ensures that the "put back" feature works.
>
> -l
>
> List items currently in the trash. If this argument is used, no files need to be specified.
>
> -e
>
> Empty the trash. trash asks for confirmation before executing this action. If this argument is used, no files need to be specified.

To install `trash` run the following in Terminal:

`brew install trash`.

---

2. ## [rmtrash](http://www.nightproductions.net/cli.htm)

   A command line tool that move files to the trash. From the command's man page:

> This command moves files to the trash rather than removing them totally from the file system.  Very useful if you decide  you  want  that  file after all...

> -u USERNAME
>
> an optional argument.  This will move the file to the specified user's trash. Note that you need sufficient privileges to accomplish this.

To install `rmtrash` run the following in Terminal:

`brew install rmtrash`.

Answer (score 1):

While it is possible to make `rm` move files to Trash instead of removing them, I would advise against bringing the mindset of the safety net of graphical user interfaces to the UNIX shell. There are many ways to do serious damage using the terminal. The best advise IMHO is to simply think twice before hitting the <kbd>enter</kbd> key in a shell window.

If you want `rm` to remind you that you are about to delete a file consider using the following alias (for `/bin/bash` put this line in `.bashrc` in your home directory):

```
alias rm "rm -i"
```

This will make `rm` request confirmation before attempting to remove *each* file.

If you have TimeMachine running (I hope so!) you can always get your file from backup. This way you can lose at most one hour of work. Which is bad enough, of course. So think again before pressing that <kbd>enter</kbd> key!

Comment: Don't do it! Installer scripts may use `rm` and hang with the alias `rm -i`.

Comment: @OldPro: `.bashrc` is only executed if the shell is interactive. Check the [man page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/bash.1.html)!

Comment: i would advise against removing safety nets, or admonishing others to do so.

Comment: I'll go against the naysayers and say that I use this trick to great effect, but it definitely should be only done knowing the pitfalls. Two not mentioned are that it trains your brain that `rm` is safer than it is which will get your in trouble on other systems. Also, if you use `-f`, `-i` is completely ignored. That said, this is a good safety net. A better one is to never use `rm` in favor of an `rmi` alias (`alias rmi="rm -i"`) or the excellent `trash` utility. Also, I'll add that everyone should have put `[ -f ~/.bashrc ] && source ~/.bashrc` in their `.bash_profile` by now.

Answer (score 0):

Properly trashing stuff (so that it is definitely recoverable) is trickier than simply a `mv` to `~/.Trash`.

[osx-trash](http://www.dribin.org/dave/osx-trash/) might be what you're looking for. (*Caveat emptor* - I haven't tried it, and cannot vouch for how safe it is.)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`trash-cli`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/trash-cli). It works cross-platform, no trash sound, and supports Put Back.

You can install it with *(requires [Node.js](https://nodejs.org))*:

```
$ npm install --global trash-cli
```

*Alternatively, if you don't want to use Node.js, you can install the native binary [`osx-trash`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/osx-trash) manually.*

Answer (score -1):

In your .bashrc (or wherever you keep the parameters for your shell), try adding an alias that changes the behaviour of rm to moving stuff to ~/.Trash, as in:

```
alias rm='move/to/.Trash'
```

This alias if far from trivial to implement (at least for me) though, because the use of mv (the prime candidate to use for this job) is

```
mv file where
```

so having an alias that puts the 'where' part in front of the file to be moved might be pretty sketchy.  I'll look into it an might get more substantial advice.

EDIT:  I just tried to add the following to my .bashrc, and it works:

```
function trash { mv "$@" ~/.Trash ; }
```

It is much more primitive than other suggestions, but you avoid installing new stuff.

Comment: Aliasing `rm` to anything is dangerous because it may break installer scripts. I learned this the hard way when I aliased `rm` to `rm -i` and had installs hang.

Comment: @Old Pro, that's the alias I use for rm in all my computers, from day 0, and I never had issues because of it.  Care to give an example?

Comment: I don't recall the specific application I was installing, but I do recall that installing it (probably an upgrade) hung and it took me about a month to figure out it was because one install script used `rm` instead of `rm -f` and the script was hung waiting for confirmation that it was OK to delete some file.  Removing the alias from my .bashrc allowed the install to complete and I've refrained from using that alias on OS X ever since, even though I still use it on every other Unix system. I'm not sure what your alias will do with `rm -f someFile`.

Comment: @OldPro: `.bashrc` is only used for _interactive_ shells. If you run `./install.sh` a new process is started and the alias will _not_ be active. However, if you run `. install.sh` your current process will execute the installer and the alias is active. RTFM...

Comment: I was using a standard installer started by double-clicking in the Finder.  I determined the process that was stuck was `rm -i` by using `ps` to see the command line and I fixed the problem by removing the `rm` alias.  YMMV

Comment: Then the installer was running an interactive shell and therefore was seriously broken. One broken installer is hardly enough reason to advise against shell aliases in general. YMMV

Comment: However, it *is* good advice to not alias the `rm` command, as morgant said, because you'll become comfortable with `rm` not actually removing files and then might accidentally delete something on a system where no such alias has been added. Also, moving a  file to the trash is *not* as simple as just `mv {} ~/.Trash`. If the file is on a separate volume, for example, this will *copy* the file to your home directory and delete the original.

Comment: I also use this short function in my .bashrc; however, you need to this change to `function trash { mv "$@" ~/.Trash ; }` to avoid it breaking on folder names with spaces in it.

Answer (score -1):

I have simply put this script

```
#!/bin/bash
application=$(basename "$0")
if [ "$#" == 0 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $application path [paths...]"
    exit 1
fi
trashdir="/Users/${USER}/.Trash"
while (( "$#" )); do
    if [ -e "$1" ]; then
        src=$(basename "$1")
        dst=$src
        while [ -e "$trashdir/$dst" ]; do
            dst=$src+`date +%H-%M-%S`
        done
        mv -f "$1" "$trashdir/$dst"
    else
        echo "$1" does not exist.
    fi
    shift
done
```

in `~/bin/trash`, made it excutable `chmod +x ~/bin/trash`, and added the following line to `~/.bash_profile`

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
```

Then one can use it as

```
$ trash broken.js olddir cleanup.*
```

Answer (score -3):

A simple function could let you trash files by moving them to the user's .Trash folder:

```
trash() {
   mv $1 ~/.Trash
}
```

Comment: ? why a negative vote? this would be my thought as well..

Comment: You probably need `$*` instead of `$1`, but then you would end up with the same answer as `mv "$@" ~/.Trash`. Why people vote it negatively, check the comments from the other answer.

Comment: Be careful with this alias; this works if you only have one partition or drive. If you're working on a second volume or network share, this will actually *copy* the file to your home directory's trash, which is probably not what you wanted to do!