# How do I enable a standard account to SSH in?

Tags: ssh, user-account

I have SSH working fine on my Mac.  I created a new "standard" account but I can't ssh in with it?  Why is this and how do I remedy it?

Comment: Why do you say you have SSH working fine when you can't use it the way you want to?

Comment: @Daniel Lawson I meant that I have it working otherwise. I am able to SSH with another account. I discovered the problem. You have to give each account permission to SSH explicitly (either individually or in a group policy). So in System Settings then Sharing I added my new user under "Remote Login" and it works fine.

Comment: @DanielLawson did you down vote me for that?

Comment: No, I didn't. But people vote for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: @DanielLawson OK, no probs...sorry for accusing you.  It was suggested to me that it didn't appear that I did research but FWIW I want to assure you I did search Google and wasn't able to phrase it to get appropriate results (I basically got stuff on setting up SSH but not the situation of activating a secondary account).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you have not enabled ssh for all users in the sharing preference pane.

Either go add the user you created or tick "Allow access for: All Users"

Comment: Yes, I figured it out as you posted this.  Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Go to System Preferences > Sharing and make sure "Remote Login" is checked. Under "Remote login", make sure that the "Allow access for" section either has "all users" checked, or has the username of the user in question added to the "only these users" box.

Comment: Thanks I selected for the individual user.  I mainly want this new user just for SSH as I got a little worried at how easy it is to make a mistake at the command line without a trashcan safety net.  So I think a standard account will be a little safer and I can just explicitly give access to this account where I need it.

Comment: I can sympathize; I wrote my own version of rm to move things to the trash instead of deleting them. See [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50844/how-to-move-files-to-trash-from-command-line) for another, hopefully more robust version that you could install.

Comment: HA!  @octern Great minds :-P  I thought of the SAME idea lol but was discouraged from "rewriting builtins" on this unix community I'm a member of (sdf1.org).  Yah I thought that would be perfect to have rm copy the deleted stuff to the trash then actually rm the file.  But it's also more than just rm, for example I had a situation where I untarred a huge directory in a place I did not intend to.

Comment: You were encouraged properly :-) *Don't* rewrite builtins. Add a new command E.G. `trash` and use that. If you switch to a different system (E.G. via SSH) it's much better to get `trash: command not found` than to accidentally `rm` a file when you thought you were moving it to the trash!

Comment: I didn't technically rewrite `rm`, I wrote `trash` and aliased `rm` to `trash` for my account. But your example goes farther, and provides a strong reason not to do that either...