# How do I delete a file that doesn't appear in finder

Tags: macos

I messed up and made the file name ... full name ....fbx. I don't really know why around the terminal. And after seeing [How to move files to trash from command line?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/50844/how-to-move-files-to-trash-from-command-line) saying that rm "not permanently deleting files." How would I move it to trash or permanently delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a filename starts with a dot (.), it is hidden and will not show by default in Finder. You can show hidden files in Finder by running the following command in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES; killall Finder
```

Then go back to the containing folder and delete the file normally.

If you don't want to keep the change regarding displaying hidden files in Finder, run

```
defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles NO; killall Finder
```

afterwards.