# Use terminal to request copy of files using Finder

Tags: terminal, finder

I can copy files using the terminal like this

```
cp -r path/to/folder1 path/to/folder2
```

However, this has some limitations:

- Conflicts are not resolved nicely: do I want to overwrite, rename, abort?
- Progress bar is not shown

Would it be possible to instead call a third party app to deal with these edge cases for me? What I am thinking in particular is programmatically telling Finder "copy these files from src to dst"

I would expect it to be something like this API

```
finder --headless --copy --src path/to/folder1 --dst path/to/folder2
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Your best bet is to use AppleScript via osascript.

Comment: Are there any resources that you recommend?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29757791/applescript-to-copy-files for instance.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this answer.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/162354/149366). (Also [see this update](https://gist.github.com/dabrahams/14fedc316441c350b382528ea64bc09c)) Altho' it's for the "Trash" function, and it uses Python, the salient bit of it is that it uses osascript to invoke `Finder`. IMHO, that's the best approach: re-use something that already works with the system.

Comment: This is how I do it on my system, although my shell functions are written in FiSh.  But it’s really good to have `rm` execute a Finder trash command, after I once accidentally deleted by system files and now never have to worry about that again.  It’s nice having an undo option for the Finder moves and copies, too.  Did you use any of the links above, or should I try and translate my FiShy functions into bashy ones, if bash is what you use?